# Python, idle - How should I fix my coding?

Tags: python

An arithmetic progression is a sequence of numbers in which the distance (or difference) between any two successive numbers is the same. This in the sequence 1, 3, 5, 7, ..., the distance is 2 while in the sequence 6, 12, 18, 24, ..., the distance is 6.

Given the positive integer distance and the non-negative integer n, create a list consisting of the arithmetic progression between (and including) 1 and n with a distance of distance. For example, if distance is 2 and n is 8, the list would be [1, 3, 5, 7].

Associate the list with the variable arith_prog.

Where should I fix in my coding?:

```
arith_prog = []  
n = int()
for i in range(1, n+distance, distance):
    arith_prog = arith_prog + i
```

Comment: What is `n = int()` supposed to do?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a few things seem strange but generally I think the problem lies in your range, simply change it to **n**, not **n+distance**

```
arith_prog = []
n = 8
distance = 2
for i in range(1, n, distance):
    arith_prog.append(i)
print(arith_prog)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arith_prog = list(range(1, n+1, distance))
```

This assumes that `n` could be included.